# how can i consolidate two company data in sage 50 accountting 2014?

Tags: accounting

I am using sage 50 accounting 2014 in four branches of our company.each branch have its own company.At the end of the year we want to consolidate the company data in all these branches to one company to get a company level report. but i am afraid of the chart of accounts in the branch companies may differ with each other.**is there a means to compare these chart of accounts before consolidating?** Please can any body me help to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Sage support cover then it's worth giving them a call and see what they say.